# Component reusable issue in Angular

Tags: angular, reusability

I am new to angular reusable components and am unsure how to reuse the component once it's built. I have 3 components  parent, container and reusable components.

parent.component.ts

```js
reUsableContent: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.reUsableContent = ReUsableContentComponent;
}
```

parent.component.html

```js
<app-container [reUsableContent]="ReUsableContentComponent"></app-container>
```

container.component.html

```js
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="reUsableContent"></ng-container>
```

container.component.ts

```js
@Input() reUsableContent: TemplateRef<any>;
```

resusable.component.html

```js
<ng-template #reUsableContent>
    <p>Reusable content works!</p>
</ng-template>
```

I am not sure if this is the way to make the reusable component. The above does not work.  What is missing from the above?

Comment: Why don't you create another component for your re-usable content? It's quite obvious that the above code doesn't work, you are passing a component class where a `TemplateRef` is expected.

Comment: Can you please share any code sample to refer?

Answer (score 0):

**1. First thing**

`TemplateRef` is not the same as `ReUsableContentComponent`

I think you need to get familiar with this: https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/typescript/typescript-how-to-create-a-templaterref-object/

**2. Second thing**

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Try to utilize `NgComponentOutlet`

Comment: Thank for sharing the link. Will try to understand the concept